# How can i hear Ibm watson text to speech audio in browser without creating .wav file?

Tags: node.js, text-to-speech, watson

I want to build an application in which i want to use text to speech IBM watson service using nodejs. Here is my code

```
var express=require("express");
var app = express();
var fs=require("fs");
var watson = require('watson-developer-cloud'); 
app.get("/",function(req,res){
var text_to_speech = watson.text_to_speech({
username: '6c1248f9-0de8-450c-8816-44a89c0e1cba',
password: 'NSkOgtjNeE5w',
version: 'v1'
 });
 var params = {
  text: 'Turkish Prime Minister Binali Yildirim today reversed an earlier 
  offer of compensation to Russia for shooting down one of Moscow military 
  jets in November, media reported.',
  voice: 'en-US_AllisonVoice',
  accept: 'audio/wav'
  };
```

// Pipe the synthesized text to a file.

```
  text_to_speech.synthesize(params)
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('lorem_ipsum.wav'));
  });

  app.listen(9000,function(err) {
if (err) {
    console.log('Error',err);
}
else{
    console.log('Connected');

}
 });
```

But in this code it is creating a `.wav` file to play, but i want to hear voice in browser directly. I don't want to create a `.wav` file to play. How can i do this using nodejs?

Comment: for your `text:` use backticks! ` instead of  quote '

Comment: here my problem is that when i run this code it creates an audio file. but i don't want to create audio file. i want to play that voice directly into browser.

Answer (score 0):

This line: `.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('lorem_ipsum.wav'));` will always pipe the contents of the stream to a file.

To hear the audio played from the browser, you will need to use a Node module that gives you access to the speakers ([such as this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/speaker)) and pipe the stream into that module.

Another option/example is [this SDK for Watson speech services in the browser](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-javascript-sdk/blob/master/text-to-speech/synthesize.js). You can use this SDK to accomplish what you're looking for, or you can use a similar approach.

Answer (score -1):

Java Solution if it helps

```
InputStream stream =service.synthesize(input, Voice.EN_ALLISON, AudioFormat.WAV).execute();
        AudioPlayer.player.start(WaveUtils.reWriteWaveHeader(stream));
```

Comment: i want it in javscript or nodejs or angular